# Can we detect the alpha and beta particles using the scintillator detectors?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, particle-detectors, gamma-rays

In the experiment gamma ray detection with scintillators, we can detect the gamma ray particle. Is it possible to detect alpha and beta particle using scintillator detectors. If not then why is so? Can we modify some experimental tools or some electronic components in order to detect alpha and beta particles?

Comment: If you consider ZnS a scintillator (which I do), then Rutherford used them quite effectively looking at alpha particles, and they also work just fine with betas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Whether a source emits $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\gamma$, it is quite reasonable to expect that the products will be emitted within the right energy range to trigger a scintillation event. Depending on the application, it might be necessary to shield the detector in such a way that only one type of radiation gets through. Or you can look at some detailed property of the scintillation pattern in order to know what should be rejected as background.

See https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nima.2008.07.008 which studies BGO's response to alphas and https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.214306 which performs an experiment with the same crystal but using gammas.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if a Scintillator’s crystal are shielded, they might not be suitable to detect alpha particles, because alpha particles are easily stopped (even by a mere sheet of paper).